# how to run Groovy script in Netbeans?

Tags: groovy, netbeans

I'm trying out NetBeans for editing Groovy code. (I'm new to Groovy, and it's been a long time since I did any Java development).

At some point I installed the Groovy plugin via the "plugins" tool.  But it does not have the green checkmark under "active", and choosing the Groovy plugin does not make the Activate/Deactivate/Uninstall buttons available.   Oh well...

So let's create a project...

1. Choose "new project".  I'm choosing "Java with Maven" just because it's the first one.
2. Hit "Finish"...and voila, I have a project.

Let's create a file...

1. Right click the project package in the left pane, choose "new"
2. Choose "Groovy Script" for a type, hit "finish"
3. Hey, I have a very simple script.  Looks like it should say "Hello chris!" when done.
4. Hit the "play" button on the toolbar....things appear in the output window.

But wait a minute...the output is "Hello World!", and it should be "Hello chris!"  It looks like "HelloWorld" is coming out of "Mavenproject1.java".

How can I (or can I) just run my script from within NetBeans?

**UPDATE**: per @andrewJames suggestion, I tried working that tutorial.   (It looks like the tutorial may be a bit out of date.)

1. I created a "Java Ant" project, as that was the only one that offered me the option of not creating a "Main Class File".
2. I created the Java form, and the Groovy class, as directed.
3. When I run the project, I get an error message saying "Error running forked groovyc".

I get that same error whether I'm running on a machine with a `groovyc` executable or not, so I suspect that there's something about the configuration that I need to change in order to point to the `groovyc` executable.

Probably something to do with the `build.xml` file...but I can't seem to figure out how to edit that to change the search path for the `groovyc` step.

Comment: Which version of NetBeans are you using? For example, with the latest version (v13) you do not need to install a plugin. Groovy will be activated automatically the first time you attempt to use it. See [this demo](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/groovy-quickstart.html) for an example. It's different from what you are trying to do, (the example uses a Groovy class, not a script) but may help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that NB doesn't run a Groovy script out of the IDE like Eclipse does. I logged an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2438) and spent more than a year on the netbeans-dev mailing list advocating for it. Often replied to with "we'll be happy to review your pull request" type of stuff. Eventually, when I rage quit the mailing list with a scathing message, Geertjan replied to the issue with a [solution](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2438?focusedCommentId=17275856&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17275856).

So, in short, use the old [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49928/pure-groovy-project) to create a Groovy project and change line 26 in `groovy-build.xml` to

```
<groovyc srcdir="@{srcdir}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" includeAntRuntime="true" fork="false">
```

You can then run your script with Shift+F6.

The project needs the Groovy jars added. It works for me on NB 11, 12 & 13 with Groovy 2.x and Java 8, 11 & 14 so far. I haven't tried it with Groovy 3.x as the groovy-all.jar is deprecated so you'll have to maven or manually manage the Groovy jars.

Also, I collaborated a bit with someone on a new [plugin](https://github.com/Enroi/GroovyScripts). It works as is but new development has stalled.